# CakePHP 2.1.1 : Execute a shell from controller

Tags: shell, cakephp, controller, console

I'm trying to execute a **Shell from my Controller** via AJAX request.

In my controller :

```
public function log_import() {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    App::import('Console/Command', 'AppShell');
    App::import('Console/Command', 'IzigetlogShell');

    $job = new IzigetlogShell();
    $job->dispatchMethod('main');

    echo "REPONSE";

  }
```

And my shell :

```
<?php
App::import('Core', 'Controller');
App::import('Controller', 'Suivis');

class IzilogShell extends AppShell {

    public $uses = array('Suivi');

        -- DU CODE --  

          $this->Suivi = new SuivisController();
          $this->Suivi->constructClasses();


          $exist_date = $this->Suivi->find('first',
              array(
                  'conditions' => array('Suivi.date' => $date_calcul)
              ));

      }
```

But i always get the same error message :
**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method SuivisController::find() in C:\wamp\www\iziboxLogs\app\Console\Command\IzigetlogShell.php on line XX**

I tried to execute the shell from the console and i got the same error.

Any ideas ? Thanks, Martin

Comment: your title is partly wrong - you also got it the other way - executing a controller from shell. either way, its an abuse of (Cake)PHP and MVC to do so. The answers you got so far are no better I am afraid.

Comment: @Mark. You're right, I focused on the Shell code and missed the fact that the Shell class was also called from the controller.

Comment: you can refer my post for your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801498/9406765 thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: You don't!

Its a violation of the MVC what cake stands for.
You need to move your "shared" code into a model and use this model only in both cases. not the controller (which is the link/logic from model and "webbrowser", not your shell). and not the shell from within the controller (since the shell is the link/logic from model and "CLI").

So:

- Model contains all the code
- Shell uses Model and its methods
- Controller uses Model and its method

=> DRY and clean

then you would also need not a single App::import (or better App::uses) statement.

PS: if you happen to have a lot of non-model code, you can also make a Lib in APP/Lib and use this as your common class.

PPS: `public $uses = array('Suivi');` is for models anyway, not for controllers (as the docs speficy by the way).

Answer (score 0):

By doing this

```
$this->Suivi = new SuivisController();
```

`this->Suivi` becomes a SuiviController and not a Suivi model anymore.

But you then use it as a model:

```
$exist_date = $this->Suivi->find(...);
```

The `find()` method is a model method, not a controller method. So if you do need to call the `find()` method, there is no need to instanciate the `SuivisController` at all.